# Arc Length for Parametric Equations $x={{\left( \cos u \right)}^{4}}$ and $y={{\left( \sin u \right)}^{4}}$

Tags: definite-integrals, arc-length

We know $-1\le \cos u\le 1$, $0\le {{\left( \cos u \right)}^{4}}\le 1$, therefore, $0\le u\le \frac{\pi }{2}$. The length itself can be calculated as

$\begin{align}
  & \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{{{\left( \frac{dx}{du} \right)}^{2}}+{{\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right)}^{2}}}du} \\ 
 & =\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{{{\left( -4\sin u{{\left( \cos u \right)}^{3}} \right)}^{2}}+{{\left( 4{{\left( \sin u \right)}^{3}}\cos u \right)}^{2}}}du} \\ 
 & =4\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{{{\left( \sin u \right)}^{2}}{{\left( \cos u \right)}^{6}}+{{\left( \sin u \right)}^{6}}{{\left( \cos u \right)}^{2}}}du} \\ 
\end{align}$

Unfortunately, I’m stuck with this integral. A hint would be very helpful. There was a similar question several years ago.
[Arc length of $f(t)=(cos^4(t),sin^4(t))$ from $t=0$, to $t=2\pi$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219179/arc-length-of-ft-cos4t-sin4t-from-t-0-to-t-2-pi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify the integrand using the double angle formulae to get

$$I=\int{\sqrt{{{\left( \frac{dx}{du} \right)}^{2}}+{{\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right)}^{2}}}\,du} =\int \sqrt{\sin ^2(2 u) (\cos (4 u)+3)}\,du$$ In the range of integration, $\sin(2u)\geq 0 $; so
$$I=\int\sin (2 u)\sqrt{3+\cos (4 u)}\,du$$ Using $\sin(2u)=t$, this gives
$$I=\frac 1{\sqrt 2} \int t\, \sqrt{\frac{2-t^2}{1-t^2}}\,dt$$ Let $t^2=x$ to make
$$I=\frac 1{2\sqrt 2} \int \sqrt{\frac{2-x}{1-x}}\,dx$$ which looks to be more pleasant.

Now,  to finish, make $\sqrt{\frac{2-x}{1-x}}=w$

Comment: I think there is a problem with substitution $t = \sin(2u)$. If you solve the integral right after it and substitute back $t = \sin(2u)$, the whole thing over $0\leq u \leq \pi /2$ evaluates to $0$, which is clearly wrong. More directly, you can see it by noting $\sin(2\cdot 0) = \sin(2\cdot \pi/2) = 0$. Perhaps one should split the integral right before the substitution into cases $0\leq u \leq \pi/4$ and $\pi/4\leq u \leq \pi/2$ with the corresponding substitutions being $u = 1/2\, \arcsin t$ and $u = \pi/2 - 1/2\, \arcsin t$?

Comment: These two parts will give the same lengths, which makes sense geometrically because of the reflection symmetry of the parametric curve with respect to the line $y= x$. Explicitly, $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin (2 u)\sqrt{3+\cos (4 u)}\,du = 2 \cdot \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \int_0^1 t\, \sqrt{\frac{2-t^2}{1-t^2}}\,dt.$

Comment: @Ennar. Good points ! I did not want to go to the definite integral.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the integral as

$$4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin t\cos t\sqrt{\cos^4t+\sin^4t+2\cos^2t\sin^2t-2\cos^2t\sin^2t}\;dt$$

$$= \sqrt{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin 2t \sqrt{1+\cos^22t}\:dt $$

This integral could be evaluated in many ways, but the simplest substitution would be $\cos 2t = \sinh \tau$ which gives

$$ \sqrt{2}\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}( 1)}\cosh^2\tau \:d\tau = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}(1)} 1+ \cosh 2\tau \:d\tau = 1+\frac{\sinh^{-1}(1)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: $1/{\sqrt 2}$ should be $\sqrt 2$ instead, right?

Comment: @Ennar I'm not sure where the error is, there is certainly a factor of $2$ missing to get the correct answer. However, $2\sin 2t \:dt = \cosh \tau \:d\tau$, so that's where that step becomes what it is

Comment: I got $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin 2t \sqrt{1+\cos^22t}\:dt = \frac 12 \int_{-\sinh^{-1}(1)}^{\sinh^{-1}( 1)}\cosh^2\tau \:d\tau = \int_0^{\sinh^{-1}( 1)}\cosh^2\tau \:d\tau.$$

Comment: @Ennar thanks for the check!

Comment: Nice solution with an unexpected change of variable. $\to +1$

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, and i'm not so sure how you may progress
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\sin^2 u \cos^6 u + \sin^6 u \cos^2 u} &= |\sin u||\cos u|\sqrt{\cos^4 u + \sin^4 u}\\
&=|\sin u||\cos u|\sqrt{(\sin^2 u + \cos^2 u)^2-2 \sin^2 u \cos^2 u}\\
&=|\sin u||\cos u|\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}(2 \sin u \cos u)^2}\\
&=|\sin u||\cos u|\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 2u}
\end{align}

Comment: Quite tedious, isn't it ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Yes Sir, it is! Good luck :-)